# How can I iterate over numbered variables (for example x1 to x100 in a loop?

Tags: python

I want to iterate over numbered variables (say x1 to x10). For example:

```
x4=spo.minimize(Agt4,1,method="BFGS").x
x5=spo.minimize(Agt5,1,method="BFGS").x
x6=spo.minimize(Agt6,1,method="BFGS").x
```

I have over 100 variables like x and Agt. Is there a way to loop over the variables? I don't want to write the code for 100 x and Agt values.

Comment: This is definitely a situation where you should be using some kind of aggregate data structure, like a list.

Comment: I think this may be an example of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). I agree with Chris that this should probably be approached with a list rather than many variables.

Comment: "I have over 100 variables like x and Agt." That's the problem, you should have never done that. You need to stop thinking in terms of "variables" and start thinking in terms of *data structures*. This sounds like these should have been in a list to begin with, then you just loop over that list.

Comment: In my opinion `Agt` should be a `list`, and likely so should `x`. Then just use normal array indexing.

Comment: If you had a proper list of `Agt` values, you could write `xs = [spo.minimize(a, 1, method="BFGS").x for a in Agts]` and be done.

Comment: It's worth noting that the accepted answer to the linked question uses dictionaries, whereas most of the comments here are suggesting lists. For same linked question, I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972761/9705687), as it (1) uses lists (2) has a more thoughtful discussion on data structures.